# pandas dataframe delete groups with more than n rows in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df = [type1 , type2 , type3 , val1, val2, val3
       a       b        q       1    2     3
       a       c        w       3    5     2
       b       c        t       2    9     0
       a       b        p       4    6     7
       a       c        m       2    1     8
       a       b        h       8    6     3
       a       b        e       4    2     7]
```

I want to apply groupby based on columns type1, type2 and delete from the dataframe the groups with more than 2 rows. So the new dataframe will be:

```
df = [type1 , type2 , type3 , val1, val2, val3
       a       c        w       3    5     2
       b       c        t       2    9     0
       a       c        m       2    1     8
  ]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Is there any condition based on what you want to delete if there are more than 2 rows or any arbitrary rows can be deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get counts of groups for `Series` with same size like original, so possible filter by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for `<=` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['type1','type2'])['type1'].transform('size').le(2)]
print (df)
  type1 type2 type3  val1  val2  val3
1     a     c     w     3     5     2
2     b     c     t     2     9     0
4     a     c     m     2     1     8
```

If performace is not important or small DataFrame is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df =df.groupby(['type1','type2']).filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2)
```